# jQuery plugin - Use options during initialization with method calls

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [this guide](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) to create a plugin for myself that creates and opens a modal. I'm using options to initialize the plugin which overrides the defaults. I also have methods that I want to use to open the modal. Problem is, when I call the method, I don't have access to options that I used during initialization. How do I deal with this?

```
$.fn.sheets = function(options){
    const sheets = this;
    let defaults = {
        type: 'standard'
    };

    const head = sheets.find('.head'),
        body = sheets.find('.body'),
        headHeight = head.outerHeight(),
        bodyHeight = body.outerHeight(),
        sheetHeight = headHeight+bodyHeight;

    if(options == 'open'){
        // opts is not defined here. extending the defaults will also not work. I need the information here if the sheet is of type standard or modal
        openSheet(sheets, head, body, opts);
    } else {
        const opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        //code to initalize the plugin

        head.on('click', function(e){
            if(sheets.hasClass('active'))
                closeSheet(sheets, head, body);
            else
                openSheet(sheets, head, body, opts);
        });
    }

    function openSheet(sheets, head, body, opts){
        //code to open modal
    }

    function closeSheet(sheets, head, body){
        // code to close modal
    }
}
```

Usage

```
//initializing with type modal
$('.sheets').sheets({
    type: 'modal'
});
$('.login-trigger').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // open the modal
    $('.sheets').sheets('open');
});
```

Comment: To answer your immediate question, try moving line `const opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);` above `if` statement and adding some debug statements (for example, in `openSheet` method). This will reveal other structural issues you'll need to address.

Comment: I can not move it up there because when I'm calling `.sheets('open')` it will try to merge `defaults` with string `open`. That is a big issue for me.

Comment: Yes, that the deeper issue. If you are trying to implement a modal, I would recommend leveraging an existing library like [this one](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal). If you need to roll you own plugin, you could refer to this one to get your own sorted out. For example, consider [this example](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal#method-2-manually).

Comment: What is exactly the deeper issue - that I'm not using an existing plugin?